# Delay of Cassandra cluster.close

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am new to Cassandra. I implemented a Java Cassandra Connector in each method a new cluster will be build and end of the method I close it.
but `cluster.close()` method take too much time to finish.
Then I tried `cluster.closeAsync()` but it did not help much. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you open the connection **once** per application, **keep it open**, **reuse the session object** (the `connect` method returns that object) **all over the places in the application**, and you apply this *criteria* until you are done with the cluster. I mean, when your application finishes its work: you close both session and cluster only when your application **quits** or you need to release resources for a while. That's how the driver is supposed to be used.

Please find more on [DataStax site](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/)

Comment: Thank you @xmas79